# InnoDB JPA, keep forcing MyISAM

Tags: mysql, jpa, innodb

My school thought it would be nice to add another requirement to our exam 80% in the process.

We now have to care about the database, not that I don't do normally, but they wanted us to use JPA and left us focusing on the diagrams and code instead.

Now they thought it over and we need to analyze the database and the relations and we, as our group don't use Windows, has not been using MSSQL as our teachers does, but MySQL.

So unfortunately we realized that our entire database is stored as MyISAM, and it doesn't seem like JPA want to do otherwise?

I've tried to add this to my.cnf (Debian server):

```
default-storage-engine=innodb
default-table-type=innodb
```

But didn't solve anything.
Is it possible to get InnoDB from JPA, so that we have base for next and last week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :D Thanks for your effort

http://blog.eflow.org/archives/145

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB
```

The part: sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

To convert MyISAM to innodb is as simple as

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There are certain restrictions on InnoDB,
such as

- maximum index length allow
- fulltext support (innodb does not support)

These are some examples:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html

Comment: Thanks. But that's not giving me my constraints

Comment: @Emil - how is your database connection being established ? Maybe worth to revise that

Comment: @Emil - Is the jdbc drive support only innodb?

Comment: Only InnoDB? No it's creating MyISAM tables.

Comment: @Emil - I mean the jdbc driver your using is supporting both myisam and innodb? If it does not support innodb, you need to replace it with another jdbc that support both storage engine

Comment: Thanks for all your effort - found the solution below :¬)